# Android : How to clear a text i.e. written by path on canvas

Tags: android

I am working on a canvas where I draw a text using Path on canvas now i want to add new string over the last string but the new string overwrite the last one, I want to clear last string and then write the new one.

How would i get this any suggestions...

Comment: change string, call invalidate()

Answer (score 0):

You have to invalidate your canvas to redraw it.

```
public setText(String text) { 
    mText = text;
    this.invalidate();
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    ...
    canvas.drawText(mText, x, y, paint);
}
```